# Doctrine inserts when it should update

Tags: doctrine

I am trying to use do the most simple update query but Doctrine issues an INSERT statement instead of an UPDATE.

```
    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->from('Image i')
        ->where('id = ?');

    $image = $q->fetchOne($articleId, Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_RECORD);
    $image->copyright = "some text";
    $image->save();
```

I have also tried using the example from the manual, but still a new record gets inserted:

```
$userTable = Doctrine_Core::getTable('User');

$user = $userTable->find(2);

if ($user !== false) {
    $user->username = 'Jack Daniels';
    $user->save();
}
```

**edit:**

This example from the manual works:

```
$user = new User();
$user->assignIdentifier(1);
$user->username = 'jwage';
$user->save();
```

The funny thing is that I use this on another model and there it works OK. Maybe I have to fetch the whole array graph for this to work (I have another model in a one to many relationship)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not, I repeat **DO NOT** use __construct() method in your models.

If you read the manual carefully you will see that you should use the construct() method (without "__" in front). Most of the things will work while using "__construct()" and calling parent::__construct() inside but the records state is not one them and this will cause all kinds of problems down the road, one of them is explained above :)

Guess we will have to wait for Doctrine 2.0 :)

Comment: Using constructor in models and entities in fine. I don't know about doctrine 1, but in doctrine 2 there aren't any problems.

Comment: This answer was written more then 7 years ago :)

Answer (score 1):

The [`replace()`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/zh/component-overview%3arecord%3areplacing-records) method works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar confusion with Doctrine. Didn't have the energy to follow through, just ended up using DQL update syntax.

```
->update('User u')
->set('u.username', '?', 'Jack Daniels')
->where(....)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
->from('Image')
->where('id = ?' $id)
->fetchOne();

$q->copyright = "some text";
$q->save();

This should work.
```